# Is it possible to create a table from another table in Excel using SQL like syntax?

Tags: sql, excel

I have a table in excel that has multiple lines per date. I'd like to create a new table that groups by date as well as a few other dimensions and sums net_revenue.

In sql it would be simple:

```
SELECT send_date,
   week_day,
   after_hours,
   discount_type,
   sum(net_revenue
FROM this_table
GROUP BY send_date,
   week_day,
   after_hours,
   discount_type
```

Is there a simple way to do this in excel? At first I thought pivot tables but I don't want each additional dimension on a new row.

This is what my current table looks like:

[image: This is what my origin table looks like]

Comment: The subtotal function should work for that.

Comment: Sorry, I should mention that there are many different dates in the table even if my screenshot doesn't show it.

Comment: You can run SQL in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following strictly GUI interface solution:

1. Copy all your grouping fields as is into a separate sheet.
2. Under Data tab of ribbon, click Remove Duplicates, selecting all columns.
3. In the final column, run `SUMIFS` formula to calculate net_revenue sum, pointing to values in you original sheet.

   ```
   =SUMIFS(<net_revenue_column>,
           <1stgroup_column_in_first_sheet>, <1stgroup_value_in_second_sheet>,
           <2ndgroup_column_in_first_sheet>, <2ndgroup_value_in_second_sheet>,
           <3rdgroup_column_in_first_sheet>, <3rdgroup_value_in_second_sheet>,
            ...
          )
   ```

---

Alternatively, actually run SQL (if using Excel for Windows) using the JET/ACE SQL Engine (same engine of MS Access that can query Excel workbooks even CSV files). Below assumes your data begins in A1 with named columns. Adjust sheet name in `FROM` clause.

```vb
Sub RunSQL()
   Dim oConn, rs As Object
   Dim strConnection, strSQL As String
   Dim i As Integer

   Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

   ' CONNECTION STRING ON CURRENT WORKBOOK
   strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
                     & "DBQ=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";"

   ' OPEN DB CONNECTION
    oConn.Open strConnection

    strSQL =  "SELECT send_date,        " _
            & "       week_day,         " _
            & "       after_hours,      " _
            & "       discount_type,    " _
            & "       sum(net_revenue) AS total_revenue " _
            & " FROM [SheetName$]       " _
            & " GROUP BY send_date,     " _
            & "          week_day,      " _
            & "          after_hours,   " _
            & "          discount_type  "

    ' OPEN RECORDSET OF QUERY
    rs.Open strSQL, oConn

    ' OUTPUT DATA TO EXCEL WORKSHEET (IN EMPTY TAB NAMED "RESULTS")
    ' HEADERS
    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RESULTS").Cells(1, i) = rs.Fields(i).Name
    Next i

    ' ROWS
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RESULTS").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close: oConn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing: Set oConn = Nothing        
End Sub
```